# Firefox extension preferences

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

How to save and get the user preferences seperatly using firefox extension.

Note: don't use the firefox core preferences. for example type about:config in firefox address bar it shows a default preferences stored in browser.

I don't need this type storage.

I need only store the user preferences collecting from the text box and save seperatly.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DOMStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage) or [simple-storage](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/sdk/1.0b4/docs/packages/addon-kit/docs/simple-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could save the text to a file:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O